# How do I do monthly / quarterly aggregations in QuestDB?

Tags: sql, database, questdb

Is it possible to do monthly / quarterly aggregations in QuestDB?

I'm trying to use SAMPLE BY, but looks like it can aggregate "past 30 days" , but not "past calendar month":

```sql
SELECT ts, min(price)
FROM my_table
SAMPLE BY 30d;
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current attempt.

Answer (score 2):

For monthly aggregates, you could use `SAMPLE BY 1M` (`M` stands for month unit):
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/sample-by/

```sql
SELECT ts, min(price)
FROM my_table
SAMPLE BY 1M;
```

Quarterly SAMPLE BY unit is not supported yet, but you can use one of the date-time functions combined with GROUP BY clause.

```sql
SELECT extract(quarter from ts), min(price)
FROM my_table;
```

Note: I didn't specify the GROUP BY clause in the above query as it's optional in QuestDB. The database will determine aggregate functions and group keys on its own.

More docs on the `extract` and other date-time functions:
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/date-time/#extract